# Cannot run sh file while extracting hadoop files via cmd

Tags: maven, hadoop

I am a starter in hadoop and I'm trying to install hadoop framework on Window 8.1.
After certain hit and trail method i was able to extract hadoop files from .tar file and using maven for building up the framework.

While it was in progress, a error occurred stating that cannot run sh file present in such and such directory.

Please see the attached image of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`sh` (which Maven is not able to execute, according to the error) is Linux shell command. You might need to check the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows) how to build Hadoop sources on Windows.

Comment: hi...yeah i know that sh is a linux command and i resolved that prob by adding gnuwin32 to my path..now i am suffering from an error "can't open msxml6.dll file and such and such directory doesn't exist" though tht directory exist..  also an error org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven -plugin error

Comment: @HarmanDatta could you please edit the question with new error details?